# Xamarin - PushAsync fails when using ContentPage.BindingContext

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have two pages, the main page, which displays informations, and a login page, which should be shown, if I'm not logged in. The main page get it's informations via the ContentPage.BindingContext attribute. I'm using following method to show the login screen: `Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new LoginPage());`

When I run the app with the ContentPage.BindingContext, the code fails with `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`. If I remove the BindingContext, start the app, and add the BindingContext with Xamarin Hot Reload, the login screen will be displayed.

Here is an excerpt from the code:
MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyCalendar"
         xmlns:iOsSpecific="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
         x:Class="MyCalendar.MainPage"
         iOsSpecific:Page.UseSafeArea="True">

<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <local:MyViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
</ContentPage>
```

MyViewModel.cs

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly MyData data;

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        data = new MyData();
    }

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

MyData.cs

```
public class MyData
{

    public MyData()
    {               
            // Fetching data .....
            case Error:
                Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new LoginPage(), true);
                break;

            case OK:
                // Execute code
                break;

            default:
                Console.WriteLine("SOME ERROR");
                break;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to show the login page?

Comment: "the code fails" - which **specific line** is causing the exception?  If you're not sure look at the stack trace.  Have you used the debugger to step through the code and determine which object on that line is null?  if it's the `PushModalAsync` line, then it's possible the exception is actually in the constructor of `LoginPage`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that. Yes, the code fails in the PushModalAsync line. By the way, it doesn't matter if I use PushModal or PushModalAsync. The constructor is the default one, and I've copied the login page from another app of mine where it works without problems.

Comment: then use the debugger to determine which object on that line of code is null

Comment: It's the line "Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new LoginPage());". When I debug step for step trough the code, it doesn't jump into the LoginPage constructor, which to me means that the error is not in the LoginPage, but in the code or method that is supposed to open the page.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/N8se9rgF Here's the stacktrace. MyData.cs:39 is the line with the PushAsync.

Comment: I've suggested **twice** that you use the debugger to determine which element is null - have you tried that?

Comment: my guess is that `Navigation` is null if you are not wrapping `MainPage` in a `NavigationPage`

Comment: I have taken the debugger here several times, and have never been able to find anything that is null. My MainPage is wrapped in a NavigationPage (MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());)

Comment: try breaking out the `new LoginPage()` to a separate line: `var page = new LoginPage();` then  `Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(page,true);`

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I've finally found the null-element: The MainPage element in Application.Current.MainPage...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the BindingContext, when set in the .xaml, still executed before the MainPage was (fully) initialized. Accordingly, an NPE always came.

I was able to fix it simply by adding a new line `MainPage.BindingContext = new MyViewModel();` in the App.xaml.cs and removing the BindingContext from the .xaml. This ensured that the BindingContext is only executed when the MainPage is completely loaded.